# How to apply transition in SASS?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, css-transitions, scale

> The transition effect works when the pointer is hovered over it. But
> it snaps back to original size when the mouse pointer is removed. I
> want the cardLink to smoothly scale to .95 and then smoothly scale
> back to the normal size.
> I am using React and Sass

```
.homepage{
        &__cardLink {
            transition: transform .9s linear; 
            text-decoration: none;
            
            @include tablet {
              height: 100%;
            }
        
            :hover {
              box-shadow: 1px 2px 9px 7px #8e8d8a;
              transform: scale(0.95);
              transition: .75s;
             
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: which element you want to hover? According to this `<element class="homepage__cardLink">
  …
    <element :hover>`
element inside `homepage__cardLink` will be hovered

Comment: @shubham Thanks! That makes so much sense now. If hover is applied to elements in(not to)       homepage__cardLink then transition(for when the pointer is moved) should be applied to elements within homepage__cardLink. This works!

Answer (score 0):

Add transform to the intial class too!

```css
.homepage {
  &__cardLink {
    transition: transform .9s linear; 
    transform: scale(1);
    text-decoration: none;
    
    @include tablet {
      height: 100%;
    }

    :hover {
      box-shadow: 1px 2px 9px 7px #8e8d8a;
      transform: scale(0.95);
    }
  }
}
```